# Perl array of hash with an element which might be another array of hash

Tags: perl, hash

assume we have this array structure:

```
push @active_connections, {
                           token => $token,
                           pending => VALID_WEBSOCKET,
                           time=>time(),
                           badge => 0,
                           monlist => $monlist,
                           intlist => $intlist,
                           last_sent=>{},
                           platform => $platform
                          };
```

I later want to add to last_sent, such that last_sent will have two values, and "id" and a "value" for that ID and this itself will need to be a list.

In other words lets assume I have ids = 1,2,3 and associated values 10,20,30
I want to be able to do:

```
$active_connections[i]->last_sent{'1'} should return 20
$active_connections[i]->last_sent{'3'} should return 30
```

How does one set up last_sent to be able to do something like this?

thanks

Comment: Matt, I'm sorry I don't quite understand. How do I populate last_sent? $active_connection[3]->last_sent{'4'}='35' ? I tried doing a foreach (@active_connections) and then my $foo = $_->last_sent; and then $foo{'1'} = 30 but last_sent seems empty

Comment: I deleted my comment and posted an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to "set up" anything. Just dereference the value in question, and [autovivification](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlglossary.html#autovivification) will do the rest.

```
$active_connections[$i]->{last_sent}->{1} = 20;
$active_connections[$i]->{last_sent}->{3} = 30;
```

Comment: Ah thank you! You can't imagine this joy I am experiencing. I've been banging my head on this since morning.

Comment: Perhaps an hour or so reading the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) will minimise the amount of time spend banging your head in the future.